# Check hashMap key contain HTML tags

Tags: android

When we change URL to incorrect value then we get HTML type response from server side that we restore in hamhMap key value on the basis of "=". The hashMap key contain HTML tags like

```
"<html>\t<head>\t\t<title>CSRFRedirect</title>\t</head>\t<body>\t\t\t\t<form method"
```

Please guide how to handle this type of key?

Answer (score 0):

check the response code of your api response. if it throws error code 500 it is server error , you can handle it 
 [check here for more info](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)